# What would be the best way of creating a drop down menu - selected go to page

Tags: 7, views

I would like to create a drop down menu that does two things and I am still new to Drupal and i am trying to figure it out. The two functions are:

1. automatically grabs the title of the pages i am trying to list.
2. When an item is selected it will navigate to the corresponding page.

I feel like this has to be doable, but i am just not sure how i would go about it. Would anyone have any ideas on how i would go about doing something like this? any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a View (with the Views module) with the Format "Jump Menu"

In the fields include the title, and link it to its node in the field settings.

If that does not serve your purpose, there are several Jump Menu contributed modules http://drupalmodules.com/search/node/jump+menu

Comment: Thank you for responding! This seems very close to what I need. I have 2 follow up questions. First, what do you mean exactly by linking the title field to its node in the field settings? Like where do I go for that? And lastly, is there a way to us the actual link associated with its page or can it only be link by title?

Comment: In the View settings for the field (Content: Title) there is a checkbox: "Link this field to the original piece of content" -- In "Pager" there are settings "Use pager:Display a specified number of items | 4 items" make sure it is not set to "1" -- also check your "Filter criteria" for "Published (Yes)" and make sure they are published and there are not other filters that would limit the results that are returned by the query

Comment: Got it! Thank you! What about the linking issue?

Comment: For more info, install the Advanced Help module https://drupal.org/project/advanced_help All Views documentation is included with its installation. Also the community docs for Views https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views

Comment: Thank you! I got it. Just had to add the content path field and make sure i excluded it from the display.